# How to Find & Replace in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

There's an option in Jupyter Notebooks where you can select some cells, and then hit F, which opens up a Find & Replace feature.

This shortcut doesn't work in Jupyter Lab. It's not in the Commands list and it's not in the Edit Menu (there is only Find -- and Find Next and Find Previous). Nor can I find a global (not specific to a cell selection) Find & Replace feature.

Does this feature exist? I've found old mentions of it on the internet -- has it been removed? I'm using Jupyter Lab version 1.2.3.

Comment: Simply `Command+F` for OSx, or `Control+F` in Windows. It will prompt find, click small arrow (as in accepted answer).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The Find & Replace feature was **not** removed, but the way it is named in the menu (simply `Find...`) and the UI which requires the user to click on a small arrow to access it may be confusing. Please see the GIF below which demonstrates how to use the search & replace feature:

[image]

If you need a slightly more powerful refactoring tool (i.e. distinguishing the variable scopes) you may want to check out my [`jupyterlab-lsp`](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp) project which now includes support for the rename action (see [here](https://github.com/jupyter-lsp/jupyterlab-lsp/releases/tag/v0.7.0) for a demonstration GIF, but please install a newer version, not the tag linked).

Comment: Got it, thank you! I can use Jupyter Lab again. This is pretty bad UI in my opinion, I think most users will miss this. Changing the toggle from an arrow to a "replace" icon, or just having replace toggled on by default, would be much better.

Comment: Actually you can also press "Ctrl+F" to enable the process above.

Comment: @krassowski Is it possible to switch between search modes, e.g. regex mode, text mode and escape character mode?

Comment: I think the `.*` button toggles regular expression.

Comment: Is it possible to limit the scope of replace to just the selected cell?

Comment: @linello there is an ongoing work to make it possible: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10067

Comment: "Confusing"? How about "virtually invisible"?

Comment: Please help JupyterLab devs improve the situation by chiming in [this thread](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6650) discussing usability of find-and-replace function. Please give thumbs up to solutions that you like, and suggest new solutions (but please avoid comments like "me too" to keep the discussion easier to read).

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. When I go to the edit menu, the find... selection is always grayed out. If I am just in the cell, or highlight some code, or choose a whole cell or choose all the cells in the notebook, it is always grayed out.

Comment: @GerryHarp please open an issue on GitHub if you want an assistance with this one.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the original question was answered correctly. If I were to find and replace in only a selected cell, the top rated solution doesn't seem to work (in JupyterLab). The desired result is obtained by clicking on the `...` button in the F&R menu. Check the attached snippet.[image]

Comment: Of note in 4.0 `...` icon was replaced with a filter (funnel) icon and moved inside the text field as are other buttons.

Comment: Now why did Jupyterlab have to go and ruin a good system.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using keyboard in Jupyter as well.

**Step 1:** If you are inside any code block/cell, press Esc.

**Step 2:** Press F

[image: Gif for illustration]